# Running Unix scripts remotely from Windows terminal and passing back prompts

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-access, putty, plink

I'm using `plink` to run a script on a remote server (Linux) from a Windows machine. Part of the script prompts for inputs (authentication to various other remote servers that use different credentials). I don't want to store the password in the script as each use will be using their own for auditing reasons.

I need the prompt to be transmitted to the Windows terminal window and I need the input transmitted back to the Linux box. Additionally I need to write log all this into a file, like this:

```
plink username@unixbox /etc/scrips/myscript.bash > report.txt
```

At the moment the above works but all that prints to `report.txt` is the prompts

```
please enter password for reportBox1?
please enter password for reportBox2?
```

Instead I need it to send the password prompt and input to the Linux box to continue running the script as it normally would, only remotely. So the output of `report.txt` would read:

```
please enter password for reportBox1? *
File 1
File 2
File 3
please enter password for reportBox2? *
Data a
data b
data b
```

Hope that makes sense. If there's something better than `plink` can be used such as putty's `ssh.exe` please let me know that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

First off: `plink` **is** PuTTY's `ssh.exe`.

If you want to be able to answer the password prompt on the Windows machine, you need to tell `plink` to allocate a pseudo-terminal with `-t`:

```
plink -t username@unixbox /etc/scrips/myscript.bash
```

Now you get the prompt and input will be sent back. But if you redirect `STDOUT` to `report.txt`...

```
plink -t username@unixbox /etc/scrips/myscript.bash > report.txt
```

...you won't see the prompt, because it's redirected into `report.txt` (although the script still runs and waits for your input). To get around this, you need some tool which allows you to redirect the output to *multiple destinations* - `STDOUT` and `report.txt` at the same time. In the *nix world, the command for this is `tee`. There are ports of `tee` for Windows:

- as part of [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) (this is what I'm using)
- as part of [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)
- as [batch](/questions/tagged/batch), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and [rexx](/questions/tagged/rexx) [versions](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/unixports.php#TEE)

Having set one of those up, you'd do:

```
plink -t username@unixbox /etc/scrips/myscript.bash | tee report.txt
```

**Security note:** If the password prompts in the script on the Linux machine echo what was input, the passwords will of course also be logged in `report.txt`, which might be a problem.